# who to find the div id contain my iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

My page contains multiple div. From each div there is a call to an Iframe.

```
 <div class="modelImge" id="div1456"><iframe src="randomImge.html"></div>
 <div class="modelImge" id="div487421"><iframe src="randomImge.html"></div>
```

The content of the iframe is changing dynamically.
Is there a way to know the id of the div.

Comment: "the div"? which DIV?

Comment: You're trying to get the id of the containing div from a script within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot access data directly across an iframe's 'border'. That means the site opened in the iframe has no access or knowlege of the iframe's encompassing div, and your base site does not have access to content provided by the iframe.

Comment: Our system is using "friendly iFrame" to allow cross domain access to the parent page. I just need to know how to make it happen

Comment: @YossiGurArie, In that case, I'm afraid I can only direct you to the documentation. You should specify such details in the original question, as it is hardly obvious. This might be a good place to start: http://classroom.emediate.com/doku.php?id=technical:integration:friendly_iframes:start

Answer (score 0):

The id of the div does not change. 
Even if the src for the iframe changes, the div that contains the frame will not change.

My question is: are you trying to find a div in your page or in "randomImag.html". If it is in your page the id will be the same, regardless of the content.

Comment: from the "randomImag.html" .My team does not have access to the  parent file

Comment: "window.frames[0].parent " might do what you want